# Input / Output operations - ML

Tags: sml, standards, smlnj, ml

I am learning ML.
Can some one please help me out with basic input/output functions in ML??
I just want to read input from console and store it in a variable and use it in my ML program.

Please help. If you can point me towards some example for this also it would be super great!!!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let val str = valOf (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn) in
  (* do stuff here *)
end
```